# mcdr: contract violation expected: mpair? given: 5

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a program in scheme that takes in regular scheme notation ex: (* 5 6) and returns the notation that you would use in any other language ex: (5 * 6)

I have my recursive step down but I am having trouble breaking out into my base case.

```
(define (infix lis)
  (if (null? lis) '()
      (if (null? (cdr lis)) '(lis)
       (list (infix (cadr lis)) (car lis) (infix(caddr lis))))))

(infix '(* 5 6))
```

the error happens at the (if (null? lis)) '(lis)

the error message is:

```
 mcdr: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: 5
>
```

why is it giving me an error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Right now your `infix` function is assuming that its input is always a list. The input is not always a list: sometimes it is a number.

```
A PrefixMathExpr is one of:
 - Number
 - (list BinaryOperation PrefixMathExpr PrefixMathExpr)
```

If this is the structure of your data, the code should follow that structure. The data definition has a one-of, so the code should have a conditional.

```
;; infix : PrefixMathExpr -> InfixMathExpr
(define (infix p)
  (cond
    [(number? p) ???]
    [(list? p)   ???]))
```

Each conditional branch can use the sub-parts from that case of the data definition. Here, the list branch can use `(car p)`, `(cadr p)`, and `(caddr p)`.

```
;; infix : PrefixMathExpr -> InfixMathExpr
(define (infix p)
  (cond
    [(number? p) ???]
    [(list? p)   (.... (car p) (cadr p) (caddr p) ....)]))
```

Some of these sub-parts are complex data definitions, in this case self-references to `PrefixMathExpr`. Those self-references naturally turn into recursive calls:

```
;; infix : PrefixMathExpr -> InfixMathExpr
(define (infix p)
  (cond
    [(number? p) ???]
    [(list? p)   (.... (car p) (infix (cadr p)) (infix (caddr p)) ....)]))
```

Then fill in the holes.

```
;; infix : PrefixMathExpr -> InfixMathExpr
(define (infix p)
  (cond
    [(number? p) p]
    [(list? p)   (list (infix (cadr p)) (car p) (infix (caddr p)))]))
```

This process for basing the structure of the program on the structure of the data comes from [How to Design Programs](https://htdp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake**

```
(infix '(* 5 6))
; = 
(list (infix (cadr '(* 5 6))) (car '(* 5 6)) (infix (caddr '(* 5 6))))
; = 
(list (infix 5) '* (infix (caddr 6)))
; =   ^^^^^^^^^
;        |
;        |
;        v
(if ...
 ...
 (if (null? (cdr 5)) ; <-- fails here
     ...
     ...))
```

**Solution**

First, you need to define the structure of the data you're manipulating:

```
; OpExp is one of:
; - Number
; - (cons Op [List-of OpExp])

; Op = '+ | '* | ...
```

In english: it's either a number or an operator followed by a list of other op-expressions.

We define some examples:

```
(define ex1 7)
(define ex2 '(* 1 2))
(define ex3 `(+ ,ex2 ,ex1))
(define ex4 '(* 1 2 3 (+ 4 3 2) (+ 9 8 7)))
```

Now we follow the structure of OpExp to make a "template":

```
(define (infix opexp)
  (if (number? opexp)
      ... 
      (... (car opexp) ... (cdr opexp) ...)))
```

Two cases:

- The first case: what to do when we just get a number?
- The second case: first extract the componenet:

  - `(car opexp)` is the operator
  - `(cdr opexp)` is a list of operands of type OpExp

Refining the template:

```
(define (infix opexp)
  (if (number? opexp)
      opexp
      (... (car opexp) ... (map infix (cdr opexp)) ...)))
```

Since we have a a list of op-exps, we need to map a recursive call on all of them. All we need to do is make the operator infix at the top-level.

We use a helper that intertwines the list with the operator:

```
; inserts `o` between every element in `l`
(define (insert-infix o l)
  (cond ((or (null? l) (null? (cdr l))) l) ; no insertion for <= 1 elem lst
        (else (cons (car l) (cons o (insert-infix o (cdr l)))))))
```

and finally use the helper to get the final version:

```
; converts OpExp into infix style
(define (infix opexp)
  (if (number? opexp)
      opexp
      (insert-infix (car opexp) (map infix (cdr opexp)))))
```

We define respective results for our examples:

```
(define res1 7)
(define res2 '(1 * 2))
(define res3 `(,res2 + ,res1))
(define res4 '(1 * 2 * 3 * (4 + 3 + 2) * (9 + 8 + 7)))
```

And a call of `infix` on ex1 ... exN should result in res1 ... resN